# Volume of a Fundamental Domain

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Exercise #1 of Chapter 6 of Stewart and Tall (algebraic number theory and FLT) p. 136 asks for the Volume of the Fundamental domain of a Lattice which is a subset of the integral lattice points of the plane. They define volume as the appropriate tripe integral of dxdydz but what solid do we integrate? We have thought of "building" a parallelpiped or Ball or Torus around each discrete point and scale them so each one integrates out to 1. This would give the desired result which is supposed to be the number of points in the Fundamental domain.

This goes against all natural instincts to compute a "VOLUME" in the plane. Are any of our ideas correct. Where do we get the "privilege" to arbitrarily construct these dimensional objects?

Comment: On page 134, they define the volume of a subset in $\mathbf{R}^n$ to be the multiple integral over the $n$ coordinates of the indicator function on the subset. Here, you are working in $\mathbf{R}^2$, so it is only a double integral.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: This is very old - but just to write it down: if $L$ is a lattice in $\mathbb R^n$, the volume is  that of the fundamental domain (i.e., which represents  $\mathbb R^n / L$), not of $L$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain, for instance.